# MongoDB - MongoEngine - How do I follow a reference from "the other side"?

Tags: django, mongodb, reference, mongoengine

since four days I'm trying to figure out how to follow a reference from one to another class, starting from the class which is beeing referenced. In SQL-Django there is a `related_name` to achieve this...

For example I have this class:

```
class MyClass(Document):
    ...
    other_classes = ListField(ReferenceField(Other_Class))
```

and this one:

```
class Other_Class(Document):
    ...
```

Now I want to go from `Other_Class` to `MyClass`... Any ideas?

Thanks,

Ron

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a test case showing how to query it:

```
import unittest
from mongoengine import *


class StackOverFlowTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        conn = connect(db='mongoenginetest')

    def test_one_two_many(self):

        class MyClass(Document):
            other_classes = ListField(ReferenceField("OtherClass"))

        class OtherClass(Document):
            text = StringField()

        MyClass.drop_collection()
        OtherClass.drop_collection()

        o1 = OtherClass(text='one').save()
        o2 = OtherClass(text='two').save()
        m = MyClass(other_classes=[o1, o2]).save()

        # Lookup MyClass that has o1 in its other_classes
        self.assertEqual(m, MyClass.objects.get(other_classes=o1))

        # Lookup MyClass where either o1 or o2 matches
        self.assertEqual(m, MyClass.objects.get(other_classes__in=[o1, o2]))
```

The main question is do you need to store a list of references in the `MyClass`?  It might be more efficient to store the relationship just on `OtherClass`..

Comment: Maybe I need  both, it is more than common scenario.

Answer (score 0):

While thinking about my problem I came up with a solution.

I just add the ID of my referenced class to my model.

Here's an example:

```
class MyClass(Document):
    ...
    other_classes = ListField(ReferenceField(Other_Class))

class Other_Class(Document):
    myclass = ReferenceField(MyClass)
```

I'm not quite sure if this is the Mongo-way to do it but I'm pretty sure it works :)

Optionally you can omit the `other_classes` attribute in `MyClass` to avoid redundancy but then you need a query like this to get the "child" objects:

```
Other_Class.objects(myclass = myclass.id)
```

Comment: This is possible but theres no need to maintain two references for the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
oc = Other_Class()
MyClass.objects.find( other_classes__all = [oc.id] )
```

Comment: good idea... but does this query has a good performance compared to my "redundant" solution?

Comment: @Ron Your solution has definetly better performance. However it might be a bit difficult to keep cross references synchronized. Actually the best thing you can do is to use `ReferenceField` in `Other_Class` and remove `other_classes` field from `MyClass`. You don't need it, since you have to query for `other_classes` anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But if I delete the 'ListField' in 'MyClass' how do I get the 'Other_Class'es starting at 'MyClass'? For example if I have a Thread and several Posts. From time to time I'd need to start at a post and get the parent thread. But in most cases I just start with the thread and need all of my posts. So how can I delete the ListField in Threads? (Yes, a post would be an embedded document within a thread, but its just an example ;) )

Comment: @Ron you just reverse what you were trying to do. Simply do the following query: `Other_Class.objects( myclass_id = myclass.id )`. This is a lot faster then using `all` with Mongo (especially if you have index on `myclass_id` field) .

Comment: thanks for the explanation! but in my case a change in the parent list is fairly rare so i think i just stick with my "redundant" solution!

Comment: @Ron Heh, do as you wish. Just remember that I warned you. :)